# Data can't be written in dolphindb distributed database

Tags: data-partitioning, distributed-database, dolphindb

I built a distributed database in dolphindb to store stock minute data. I partitioned the data by `date` and `symbols` and append the data using the following script for testing.  I'm confused why the last query return 0?

```
data = loadText ('/mnt/data/201905.csv')
//select count(*) from data == 10950032
Syms = symbol (['000001','001001','002001','003001','999999'])
db_date = database (, VALUE, 2019.06.23... 2019.12.31)
db_sym = database (, RANGE, syms)
dB = database ('dfs://stock_minute1', COMPO, [db_date, db_sym])
partitionedTableHandler = db. createPartitionedTable (data,'minute', ['date','symbol'])
partitionedTableHandler.append!(data)
//select count(*) from loadTable('dfs://stock_minute1')== 0//?why
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are importing data of May 2019. However, your database partition schema specifies a date range of 2019.06.23 and 2019.12.31. That is no data falls within the date range. That is the reason your got zero rows.